# Cloudformation template to attach multiple filesystems to a single EBS volume

Tags: aws-cloudformation

Can someone point me in the direction as to how I can attach multiple ext4 filesystems to the same EBS volume in a Cloudformation template?

Should I use AWS::Cloudformation::Init to run commands?

Answer (score 0):

For a running instance, you can use [AWS::EC2::VolumeAttachment](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ec2-ebs-volumeattachment.html) to:

> Attaches an Amazon EBS volume to a running instance and exposes it to the instance with the specified device name.

Obviously, attaching the volume is the first step. If its brand new volume, you have to format it and mount from inside the instance.

For a new instance created using CFN, you can `AWS::Cloudformation::Init` or `User Data` to run commands to mount and/or format the volumes.